# Multi Maven Modules + Build child module with dependent project module in child module

Tags: java, maven, module, multi-module

I have a parent multi module maven project

1 parent - 3 children

1.core
 2.rest
 3.batch

Scenario: 
**Rest is dependent on core.
Batch is dependent on core.**

If I build a Rest project than the dependent core project should also get build internally through pom. 
and similarly, If I build a Batch project than the dependent core project should also get build internally through pom in m2 folder of maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can build by using something like

```
mvn clean install -pl rest -am
```

which will then build `rest` and its dependencies, which is `core`.

Comment: What do you mean by "describe POM"? Is this an additional question, or is this about my answer?

Comment: It's resolved now. Thanks for the comment.  @JF Meier

Comment: It would be great if you either add an answer yourself or accept mine.